# How to change text color after X amount of seconds?

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code:

```
<font color=green>
     14:00
</font><br>
<font color=green>
     14:30
</font><br>
<font color=green>
     15:00
</font><br>
........
```

How can I change color (in red) of every single text after some time has passed?

I have tried this code but obviously it doesn't function (`onLoad` is only for the body/img tags):

```
<font color=green onLoad="setTimeout('this.style.color=red',xxx-seconds);">
     14:00
</font><br>
```

Any suggestions?

**Solution adopted (thanks to minitech):**

```
<style>
    @keyframes change {
        from { color: green }
        to   { color: red }
    }
</style>

<span style='animation: change (number-of-seconds)s step-end both;'>
    14:30
</span>
<span style='animation: change (number-of-seconds)s step-end both;'>
    15:00
</span>
.............
```

Comment: Don't use the `font` tag! Instead mark up the element in `HTML` and then style it with `CSS`. Also you should probably separate your Javascript from the element.

Comment: `<font>` element? `color` attribute? `onLoad` attribute? String value in `setTimeout`? Mom, what year is it? *drinks a sip of coffee to wake up*

Comment: @Zenith – it's valid again in [HTML6](http://html6spec.com/) though (if that's a thing... which it isn't, thank god).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You *could* use CSS animations for this:

```css
font {
    animation: change 3s step-end both;
}

@keyframes change {
    from { color: green }
    to   { color: red }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/7ZrtQ/

In the above code, the delay is defined by `3s` which represents 3 seconds.

Btw, if you don't want to have the timer execute on page load, but instead want to have it triggered by some subsequent event (e.g. a user click), you can define the animation in a CSS class, and then just add that class to the element later with JavaScript to trigger the effect.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/7ZrtQ/3/

[image]

Comment: Plus one - Superb. Very helpful. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

Something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].style.color = "#cccccc";
},3000);
```

Because `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of `<p>` elements, we want to select the first one, with `[0]`, because the array count starts from 0.

You might need to change the `getElementsByTagName` part to a `<span>` tag. Alternatively, there's `getElementById`.

**getElementsByClassName**

Alternatively,if you want to target each element with the same class, you can do:

```
function targetGroup(className){
    // loop throgh the elements
    var elemArray = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for(var i = 0; i < elemArray.length; i++){
        elemArray[i].style.color = "#ffff00";
    }
}

setTimeout(function(){
    targetGroup('foo'); // this is the class name you are targetting.
},2000);
```

And your HTML would look like:

```
<span class="foo">bar</span>
<span class="foo">bar</span>
<span class="foo">bar</span>
<span class="foo">bar</span>
<span class="foo">bar</span>
<span class="foo">bar</span>
```

Code modified from the example on this page : http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=881

Comment: You should give more explanation as well. The OP has no `<p>` elements. Explain to him why you chose that in your example. Explain to him why `[0]` is selecting the first element in the returned result. Etc.

Comment: Yeah as much as I love jQuery, there's no need for it in this case - Vanilla JS ftw for things like this.

Comment: Also, might try explaining to him how to attach this to the `onLoad` event like he originally was attempting to do.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to not use `font` tag, instead use `span` tag.
Here is the working example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rF4SV/2/).

**HTML**

```
<span id="text">text</span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var text = document.getElementById('text');
text.addEventListener("load", init(), false);

function changeColor() {
    text.style.color = "#F00";
}

function init() {
    setTimeout(changeColor, 3000);
}
```

Here is the brief description of each JavaScript function I've used in the code.

**getElementById**

> *Returns the reference to the DOM element by its `ID`.*
>   *For more information about this function you can refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)*
>   *For alternative functions check [this URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)*

In my example, I've passed `'text'`, which is an `ID` of my `SPAN` tag.

**addEventListener**

> *Registers the specified `listener` on the `EventTarget` it's called on, which can be any object that supports `events`.*
>   *For more information about this function you can refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)*

In my example, I've registered `init()` `listener` on the `text` object, which will be called on `load` event.

**setTimeout**

> *Calls a function or executes a code snippet after specified delay.*
>   *For more information about this function you can refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)*

In my example, I've passed `changeColor()` function as an argument, so it will be called after 3 seconds delay (**Note:** the delay is in **milliseconds**).

So, here is the final process:

1. The element was loaded
2. `init()` function was called
3. 'setTimeout()' function was called
4. 'changeColor()' function was called after 3 seconds
5. The element's color was changed

Comment: Please expand your answer to include more detail, rather than just posting a link to JSFiddle.

Comment: What would you like to see?

Comment: Explain to him that he needs to add the `id="text"` attribute to the element he wants to change. Maybe go into detail about what an `id` attribute is and that it should be a unique identifier.

Comment: Also, please explain to the author how to attach this to the `onLoad` event unobtrusively like he was originally doing.