# How can I make text change colour at a certain time in my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to have some text on my webpage change from grey to purple about 2 seconds after the page loads. Do I need to use CSS for this?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17321098/1675954 You don't need Javascript, just CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS as well. But you will require JS as per my knowledge.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // your code here
   setTimeout(function() {
      var el = document.getElementsByClassName('initial_color');
      for (var i = 0, n = el.length; i < n; ++i) {
          var curr = el[i];
          curr.classList.add('changed_color');
      }
      
   }, 2000);
}, false);
```

```css
.initial_color {
  color: gray;
}

.changed_color {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="initial_color">
  Hello world
</div>
```

Comment: False. You don't need JavaScript for this. You can use CSS KeyFrames function.

Comment: @mwilson you still need to watch for the page to be loaded before firing up animation ;)

Comment: @mwilson indeed , provide a working example and an answer ;) , i run through this about 6 years ago playing with animation and keyframes , i had to relay on javascript to make it bullet proof. transition also did not work even 95% of the time. connection speed, size of the document and files to upload make it average.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of doing it with pure css. You don't need JavaScript to do this so long as you're simply wanting to just change the color of something after 2 seconds.

Use CSS [KeyFrames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) antimation:

```css
#test {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  from { background-color: grey; }
  to { background-color: purple }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Give this approach and see if it fires when/how you would expect. The only portion that this will not handle is if you truly need a full DOM rendering before firing the animations. If that is the case, then you may require a little JavaScript.

Comment: animation-delay starts once the css is loaded , works fine with a single snippet but not bullet proof ;) , window.onload is necessary to my own opinion . thanks for the demo anyway :)